# Error using "n-of" command with a breed in Netlogo

Tags: variables, nested, set, grouping, netlogo

I'm running into trouble with using the "ask n-of # " command.. got an "expected number here, rather than a list or block" error message.

Added the main chunks of code that pertain to this error.
Wondering if anyone can help?

Goal: Looking to have solar power charge only 6 of squad1 at a time (squad1 is my breed of 10 turtles). Annotated below...

```
    breed [squad1 squad1s]

    turtles-own
    [individual-power
    solar-delay
    power-count1
    count-recharge1]
```

Setup

```
    to setup 
    clear-all
    setup-patches
    setup-turtles
    reset-ticks
    end

    to setup-turtles
    create-squad1 10
    ask squad1
    [
    set color blue
    set shape "person"
    set size 1.7
    set individual-power 100
    set heading 90
    set solar-delay 0
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    ]
    end
```

To Go

```
    to go
    ask squad1 [
    if individual-power >= 15
    [forward 1
    set label individual-power
    set individual-power individual-power - 1
    set solar-delay solar-delay + 1]

    if recharge-options1 = "external-solar1" [solar-battery1]
    ]
    tick
    end
```

Solar-Battery1 Code

**This is chunk of code I need help with. I get an "expected number here, rather than a list or block" message where Netlogo highlights everything right after "ask n-of 6 squad1s ["

```
    to solar-battery1
    ask n-of 6 squad1s [ 
    if solar-delay >= 85
    [set individual-power 15]
    if solar-delay >= 91 ; increase in 6 ticks..
    [set individual-power 100
    set individual-power individual-power - 1
    set solar-delay 0]
    ]
    end
```

Update...
Having a similar issue again (n-of command isn't working) but have my turtle plurals ARE correct this time (hah). Any ideas? When I try to run this code, all five turtles perform the function, not the random 2 that I want.

```
    turtles-own
    [ battery_1
    ]

    to setup
    ca

    reset-ticks
    create-turtles 5
    ask turtles [
    set color blue
    set shape "default"
    set size 1.5
    set xcor 0
    set ycor who
    set battery_1 100 
    ]
    end

   to go
   turtles-use-power
   if recharge-options = "refresh-combat-load" [refresh-combat-load] 
   tick
   end


   to turtles-use-power
   ask turtles [
   if battery_1 >= 15
   [set battery_1 battery_1 - 4 * round random-float 1
   set label battery_1 ]
   ]
   end


   to refresh-combat-load ;;
   ask n-of 2 turtles [
   if battery_1 <= 15
   [set battery_1 100 ]]
   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have your breed declaration backwards- it should be plural then singular forms. Try this toy model:

```
breed [squad1s squad1]

to setup
  ca
  create-squad1s 10 
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask n-of 6 squad1s [
    fd 1
  ]
end
```

You should see only 6 turtles moving per call to `go`. Note that if you change to this more common structure, you will need to update your other related calls from  `ask squad1 [ ...` to `ask squad1s`.

If, however, you *intended* `squad1` to be the plural, then your call to `n-of` should read as `ask n-of 6 squad1 [...`.

###### Edit

I have slightly modified your code to check whether all `turtles` are 'refreshing combat load' and I'm not showing that behavior- only two turtles per tick are refreshing the load. With this (very slightly) modified version of your edited code:

```
turtles-own [ battery_1 ]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  create-turtles 5
  ask turtles [
    set color blue
    set shape "default"
    set size 1.5
    set xcor 0
    set ycor who
    set battery_1 100 
  ]
end

to go
  print word "Current tick: " ticks
  turtles-use-power
  refresh-combat-load
  tick
end


to turtles-use-power
  ask turtles [
    if battery_1 >= 15
    [set battery_1 battery_1 - 4 * round random-float 1
      set label battery_1 ]
  ]
end

to refresh-combat-load ;;
  ask n-of 2 turtles [
    show "I am refreshing combat load"
    if battery_1 <= 15 [
      set battery_1 100 
    ]
  ]
end
```

When I run go with the new print statement, only two turtles are being queried by `refresh-combat-load`:

[image]

Can you explain a little further what behavior you're expecting to see that is not occurring here?

Comment: That was the fix! Thank you so much!!! @luke c

Comment: Updated question above... hoping someone could help. Idk why "n-of" is stumping me so much.

Comment: @ABC - Just fyi, if you would like wider view of these revisions you would likely be better served by asking a new question since a comment on a user's post will only flag that user.  However, I'm happy to try to help in this case- please have a look at the revised answer above (which is mostly a request for more information).

Comment: @ Luke C - thanks so much for the help! (& good copy on making a new question next time)
After running what you suggested I see where my explanation lacks..
- As the battery_1 "drains over time" (battery_1 - 4 * random float), I'd like the same two  (but randomly chosen) turtles out of the five to have their battery_1 jump back up to 100. And the other three to stop at 0.


Right now with your suggestions, I see that on every tick, two randomly selected turtles are saying they are refreshing combat load, and they all eventually jump up to 100.

Comment: @ Luke C- Update.. So I got rid of the float and was able to see that yes- the code was working (I think the randomness affected the refresh-combat-load command ... I wasn't able to see a consistent repetition of two turtles refreshing combat load because everyone was slightly "off" cadence). However, I ran the command a few times, and it does a 2-1-0 sequence... where it recharges 2 turtles, then 1, then none.. essentially stopping the "15 to 100" recharge after 3 cycles. Any suggestions on ways to adjust the cycle to consistently recharge 2 turtles?

Comment: @ABC - if I understand you correctly, you want two random turtles to be able to refresh, while the others drain to zero. If that's the case, you could do something to 'mark' the two turtles (either when the turtles are created, or when you pick the two to recharge). There are many ways to do that, but one would be to create a 'rechargeable' turtle variable that acts as a flag (eg, `ask turtles with [rechargeable] [ ... ]`. Let me know if that makes sense with what you're after!